# How to connect Google Maps to my tables or resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

i wanted to know if this is even possible. I'm trying to figure out how to connect a resource to the Google Maps API. I am trying to do something like Yelp. This is what i mean:

1. Users add Dogs(name) and the weight (number)
2. Users type in location ( or near) to bring up results just like using Google Search.
3. Users verify address and then they can click Done, thus adding where the dog is located, name and weight and my application checks for all validations or the presence of the 3 parts needed.

So can anyone please help a RoR newbie out? Tips, tricks, other methods of doing this and guides would be great. I looked at the Google API but wasn't exactly sure where to start. if you need more information let me know!

Thank you!

P.S. Here is the first way i had in mind how to do this:

Users add Dog name and weight ------> then Users find location by Ajax search bar in my page -----> click to submit that it is the correct location and it places a Marker ---->  Users click done and it saves Marker on site along with a remembering the Marker for the specific Dog/weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your rails variables into javascript making it fairly easy to create markers to add to a Google map. You do this by using the embedded ruby like var lat = <%= dog.lat %>;.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var map;
  var markersArray = [];

function initialize() {
  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(0, -73.15);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: start,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    mapOptions);
  markerFromDB();
}

function markerFromDB() {
<% dogs.each do |pin| %>
    var lat = <%= pin.lat %>;
    var lon = <%= pin.lon %>;
    addMarker(lat, lon, gbid);
<%end%>
}

function addMarker(lat, lon) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
  });
  markersArray.push(marker);
}

// Initialize map on window loading
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Remember that the google maps is just an "image" of sorts and that every time you modify your database and the page reloads your map will be redrawn matching your database.

Comment: This doesn't require the plug in gmaps4rails i can just look at the Google Maps API and add the above?

Comment: No this does not require the plugin. This uses the javascript api mixed with embedded ruby that cycles through the dog database. This is based off of some of the examples you can find on Google Maps API. It should work just adding to your page because this is a simplified version of one of my partials.

Comment: @scradge As i am a newbie, i am curious. Where did you learn how to do that, is their certain books or guides out there for putting Ruby/Rails inside of javascript?

Comment: @JustinRoR Im glad this helped. To be honest I am fairly new in RoR, but my first project was using Google Maps so I have gotten (a little) familiar with it. I actually pieced together this information from stackoverflow answers and reading the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/. From my understanding ruby can go just about anywhere if enclosed in the <% %>.

Comment: I feel like I should also mention that the Google Maps api will be different than what you will view on their official website so don't beat yourself up trying to fix it. SO question #3289039 demonstrates this nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the Google-Maps-For-Rails project?  Not sure if it does exactly what you need, but it would seem like the place to look first.  https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Additionally, you could do worse than start off by watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvpcnRzkzuE.  Starting at 6:35 into the video, the presenter starts showing how to write an app that will allow people to create and rank coffee shops on a Google Map.  This sounds not unlike what you are trying to achieve.  No Ruby on Rails content in the talk, but if you're trying to figure out where to start with Google Maps API, then it should be helpful.